Existence of degree $n$ best approximation polynomial implies Existence of degree $n+1 $ best approximation polynomial
There exist a degree $n+1$ polynomial of best approximation if there exist a degree $n$ polynomial of best approximation
This is the context of the question.
If there exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree n, there also exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree n+1.
This is another question been asked with same purpose as this one that hasn't been answered. That is, for a method of solution that is relevant to the text's level, the problem is from an elementary analysis text Zorich Mathematical Analysis I Chapter 4.
So my problem is that just like the second link, I need a rather elementary solution to this problem, which I assume can be achieved, but have not been achieved myself.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Fix $[a,b]$ an interval, and $\mathcal{P}_n$ the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$.
Given two bounded functions $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, denote by $\Delta(f,g) = \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x) - g(x)|$. Denote by $E_n(f) = \inf_{P\in \mathcal{P}_n} \Delta(f,P)$.
1
Claim If $f$ is bounded, then there exists $p_0\in \mathcal{P}_0$ such that $\Delta(f,p_0) = E_0(f)$.
Proof Sketch: if $p\in \mathcal{P}_0$, then $p(x) \equiv a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\Delta(f,p) = \max( \sup f - a, a - \inf f)$, so the solution is $p_0(x) \equiv \frac12 ( \sup f + \inf f)$.
2
Claim If $q$ is a polynomial, there exists a $\lambda_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Delta(f, \lambda_0 q) = \inf_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}} \Delta(f,\lambda q)$.
Proof Sketch: By triangle inequality we have
$$ |\lambda| \Delta(0,q) = \Delta(0,\lambda q) \leq \Delta(f,\lambda q) +  \Delta(f,0) $$
so $\Delta(f,\lambda q) \to +\infty$ as $\lambda \to \pm \infty$.
Similarly, we have
$$ |\Delta(f,(\lambda + s)q) - \Delta(f,\lambda q)| \leq |\Delta(0,sq)| \leq |s| \Delta(0,q) $$
so that the mapping $\lambda\mapsto \Delta(f,\lambda q)$ is Lipschitz continuous.
The previous two paragraphs implies that the minimum is attained at some $\lambda_0$.
3
A polynomial $p_n\in \mathcal{P}_n$ is said to be a best degree $n$ approximation to $f$ if $\Delta(f,p_n) = E_n(f)$.
Claim If for every bounded function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ there exists a best degree $n$ approximation, then the same fact holds for degree $n+1$.
Proof: Denote by
$$ \xi(\lambda) = E_n( f - \lambda x^{n+1}) $$
Note that
$$ \inf_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} \xi(\lambda) = \inf_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}} \inf_{p\in \mathcal{P}_n} \Delta(f, \lambda x^{n+1} + p) = \inf_{q\in \mathcal{P}_{n+1}} \Delta(f,q) = E_{n+1}(f) $$
So it is enough to prove that $\xi$ attains a minimum.
To do so, in view of the extremum value theorem, it is enough to prove that $\xi$ is continuous and that $\xi$ tends to infinity as $\lambda \to \pm\infty$.
$\xi$ is continuous
Observe that for a fixed $p\in \mathcal{P}_n$, we have
$$ |\Delta(f, \lambda x^{n+1} + p) - \Delta(f, (\lambda + s) x^{n+1} + p)| \leq |s| \Delta(0,x^{n+1}) $$
So we have, given $\lambda, \lambda'\in \mathbb{R}$, setting $q_\lambda$ to be the best approximation to $f - \lambda x^{n+1}$, that
$$ \xi(\lambda') \leq \Delta(f - \lambda' x^{n+1}, q_\lambda) \leq \Delta(f - \lambda x^{n+1}, q_\lambda) + |\lambda - \lambda'| \Delta(0, x^{n+1}) = \xi(\lambda) + |\lambda - \lambda'| \Delta(0,x^{n+1})$$
Swapping the roles of $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$ we find that
$$ |\xi(\lambda) - \xi(\lambda')| \leq |\lambda - \lambda'| \Delta(0,x^{n+1}) $$
showing that $\xi$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous.
$\xi$ is proper
Denoting again $q_\lambda$ the best degree $n$ approximation to $f - \lambda x^{n+1}$; denote also $r$ the best degree $n$ approximation of $x^{n+1}$.
We have that
$$ \xi(\lambda) = \Delta(f, \lambda x^{n+1} + q_{\lambda}) \leq \Delta(f, \lambda x^{n+1} - \lambda r) \leq \Delta(f,0) + |\lambda| \Delta(x^{n+1}, r) = \Delta(f,0) + |\lambda| E_n(x^{n+1}) $$
Similarly
$$ |\lambda| E_n(x^{n+1}) = |\lambda|\Delta(x^{n+1}, r) \leq \Delta(\lambda x^{n+1}, -q_{\lambda}) \leq  \Delta(f,0) + \Delta(f, \lambda x^{n+1} + q_{\lambda}) = \Delta(f,0) + \xi(\lambda) $$
and so we have that
$$ |\xi(\lambda) - |\lambda| E_n(x^{n+1})| \leq \Delta(f,0) $$
We next note that $E_n(x^{n+1}) > 0$, as it is not possible to perfectly match a $n+1$ degree polynomial by a polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_n$. This shows that $\xi(\lambda)$ must grow linearly in $\lambda$ toward $+\infty$.

Inside $\xi$ is proper, the last inequality doesn't follow directly from the premise.

You are right! Can you unaccept the answer? The strategy I had for proving $\xi$ is proper doesn't even make sense now that I think about it more.

@OwenAn fixed. My previous version used the triangle inequality between the "wrong legs" of the triangle. Basically the idea is that if $f$ is bounded, then relative to the uniform norm, $\lambda x^{n+1} - f$ looks more and more like $\lambda x^{n+1}$ as $\lambda \to \pm\infty$. And our premise shows that $E_n(\lambda x^{n+1})$ grows linearly in $\lambda$.
